# How do I make frame environment play nice with \textbf?

Tags: fonts, formatting, environments, framed

I am getting a strange error message when I put textbf into a frame environment.

Minimal Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\textbf{Lemma 1}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Error Message:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   }
l.8 \textbf
           {Lemma 1}
```

When I comment out the \textbf, the file compiles fine.
When I use \textbf normally, the file also compiles fine.

Note: I am using pdflatex on Linux.

Comment: It appears that it works fine with {\bf Lemma 1} instead, but that does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want to use `beamer`'s `frame` environment, or LaTeX's `\frame` command (which I haven't even known before:). If the former is the case, you're not loading the beamer class! If the latter: `\frame` is a command, not an environment. It takes only one argument: in your case, this will be a lone `\textbf` --- thus the error.

Thus, either:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
```

or:

```
\frame{\textbf{Lemma 1}}
```

Or, the third `framed`:

```
\usepackage{framed}
% ... 
\begin{framed}
  \textbf{Lemma 1}
\end{framed}
```

Comment: I was trying to use the one in package "framed". See my comment on A.Ellet's answer.

Comment: Then the environment is called `framed`, not `frame`.

Comment: It appears that framed does exactly what I was looking for. 
I was deceived by the slide. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not famliar with the `frame` environment.  But the error seems to suggest that the `frame` environment takes some kind of argument and `\textbf` is getting slurped into that argument *sans* `{Lemma 1}`.  This is why `{\bf Lemma 1}` appears to work.

Where did you run across `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\listfiles
\usepackage{mdframed}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\textbf{Lemma 1}

\end{frame}

vs.

\begin{frame}{The}
\textbf{Lemma 1}

\end{frame}

\framebox{\textbf{Lemma 1}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Slide 6 of this slide deck said to replace "shaded" with "frame"
http://www.slideshare.net/linjaaho/how-to-make-boxed-text-with-latex

Comment: Then this is a question about `beamer` and you want to use `\documentclass{beamer}` and not `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: Changing the class as I suggested will circumvent your original error.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed the slide that said this presentation is about Beamer. I'm trying to write boxed text in a document, not a slideshow.

Comment: I upvote this answer because it provides a lot of useful information, but accepted the other one because it answered my intended question.

Comment: `\frame` is indeed defined in the LaTeX kernel, but I think it's not even documented in the manual (I'll check later); its purpose is, of course, to frame its argument, but it has been superseded by the more powerful `\framebox` command.